# var w = q||q2; what does this expression means?

Tags: javascript

what does this means?

```
var q = [];
var q2 = ["canada","usa","mexico"];
var w = q||q2;
document.writeln(w);
```

the value of the variable w is : [] the empty list.

can someone explain to me why it is displaying this [] instead of ["canada","usa","mexico"].

Comment: Because `[]` is an array object which is considered a truthy value. `q.length ? q : q2;`

Comment: Not empty; falsy. But `q` is truthy, so `q||q2` will evaluate to `q`

Answer (score 1):

You should read [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) from MDN. According to the documentation

> The logical operator OR (`||`) `expr1 || expr2`
>
> Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to `true;` otherwise, returns
>   `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either
>   operand is true; if both are false, returns false.

In a nutshell, logical operators evaluate from left to right. In your situation, since you have declare `q` as an empty array (`[]`), it evaluates to true and immediately goes and assigns `w` to that.

If you want `q2` to take precedence, you can simply do

```
var w = q2 || q;
```

so that way only if `q2` evaluates to falsey will it assign `w` to be `q` instead. The other option is to not declare `q` at all or declare it as something falsey. You can find out what evaluates to `false` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean#Example:_Creating_Boolean_objects_with_an_initial_value_of_false).